# Mule Anypoint Platform 2.0 on premise

Tags: mule

I read that Mulesoft will be launching Anypoint Platform 2.0 on premise in next month. I couldn't find much information about its features. does anyone knows what new features will be included and any link to refer will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The current version (May, 2017) of Anypoint Platform Private Cloud Edition is 1.5.2 and we are working in the next version, 1.6. You can find more information in https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-private-cloud/v/1.5/